# Address-of operator (&) vs reference operator(&)

Tags: c++

I am kind confused about this case:

Declare a pointer:

```
int b =10;
int*a=&b;
```

Here & takes the address of b.

Consider another example:

```
/* Reference to the calling object can be returned */

Test& Test::func ()
{
   // Some processing
   return *this;
}
```

this should be a pointer, *this is the obeject pointed.
But here we are asking to assign *this to &Test.

What should we modify the code to let the function return the address. Should we still use Test& ?

Comment: Make it return a pointer.

Comment: Pay attention on position of `&`: in `Test&` it is on right, but in `&b` it is on left. Also important is that `Test` is a type, but `b` is an object/variable.

Comment: There are only so many keys on a keyboard, and the letters and digits already have other uses. On an unrelated note, there's no such thing as a "reference operator". `operator` in C++ has a specific meaning, it applies to expressions not types.

Comment: @VolAnd While a nice observation, this isn't a good rule to follow as this is completely arbitrary. My favorite example is `f(int *&a)` or f(int*& a)`. What is this? One might never know.

Comment: @henrikgiesel This is definitely `f(int*&   a)`, i.e. pointer that is passed by reference to function `f()`. It is a reasonable alternative to using pointer-to-pointer (i.e. `f(int** a)`) for functions that allocate memory in body (or change address for any other reason)

Answer (score 16):

In C++ there're two different syntax units:

```
&variable; // extracts address of variable
```

and

```
Type& ref = variable; // creates reference called ref to variable
```

Easy usage example:

```
int v = 5;

cout << v << endl; // prints 5
cout << &v << endl; // prints address of v

int* p;
p = &v; // stores address of v into p (p is a pointer to int)

int& r = v;

cout << r << endl; // prints 5

r = 6;

cout << r << endl; // prints 6
cout << v << endl; // prints 6 too because r is a reference to v
```

As for using references in functions, you should google "passing by reference in C++", there're many tutorials about it.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, `this` is a pointer. The `*` dereferences the pointer, meaning `return *this;` returns the object, not a pointer to it.

Secondly, `Test&` is returning a reference to a `Test` instance. In your case, it is a reference to the object. To make it return a pointer, it should be `Test*`.

It makes more sense if you read a pointer declaration from right to left.

```
Test* func(); //When I call func, and dereference the returned value, it will be a Test
```

Answer (score 3):

> But here we are asking to assign `*this` to `&Test`.

No... you're asking for the value/expression `*this` to be used to return a `Test&`, which is a *reference* to a `Test` object.  What that does is return a reference to the object on which `func()` is invoked.

> What should we modify the code to let the function return the address. Should we still use `Test&` ?

You should use `Test*` instead... pointers *are* addresses, and having changed the return type you could return `this` (which is a pointer), but not `*this` because `*this` is not a pointer.