# Why aren't this two pointers to a node value equal?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, nodes, c++17

I want to create a linked list with pointers. So I created a struct with a pointer and a value, the pointer being the one pointing to the next node of the list.

When I tried to set a poniter to the next node, i wanted to change the value of the next node by pointing at it from the first node, but when I  try to show the value by accesing directly from the node structure i get another result, how can I make those to be equal? So that if I change one, no matter from where, the node changes its value.

This is for a university project where we need to use linked lists. I am just starting on the pointers subject so I accept any help.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    double val;
    node *nxt;
};

int main()
{
    node n1, n2;

    n1.val = 10;
    n1.nxt = new node{n2};

    n1.nxt->val = 20;

    std::cout << "List:\n";
    std::cout << n1.val << "\n"
              << n2.val << "\n";
}
```

**Actual result:**

List:

10

1.39065e-309

**Expected result:**

List:

10

20

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
n1.nxt = new node{n2};
```

to

```
n1.nxt = &n2;
```

The reason what you did, didn't work is because you are creating a copy of **`n2`** with **`new node{n2}`** (because C++ defines an [*implicit copy constructor*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Implicitly-declared_copy_constructor) for your [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810163/c-implicit-copy-constructor-for-a-class-that-contains-other-objects)) and therefore it is this copy that had its **`val`** changed to **20**.

By using the address-of <sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35594562/2089675)</sup> operator (**`&`**), you are able to assign the pointer to the address of **`n2`** and thus able to change its value with **`n1.nxt->val = 20`**.

Comment: An answer should probably contain some kind of explanation of why OPs code was wrong and how this is different. Otherwise you can simply leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much that was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are actually allocating a new `node`, not actually setting your `nxt` link to hold the actual `n2` node.

If you wish to add this node to the linked list, you should use the address of (`&`) operator:

```
n1.nxt = &n2;
```

Keep in mind this isn't recommended to create linked lists this way, particularly if you are doing this in a helper function like `addNode()` because `n2` will get destroyed once the function exits. Thus, it's usually better to use `new` or equivalent for this when you can. That would look something like this:

```
n1.nxt = new node(/* node constructor parameters */);
```

Or, if you want to make a copy about an existing `node`:

```
n1.nxt = new node{n2};
```

Comment: Thank you! You provided an extra value to the answer :)

Comment: You're welcome. Note that any answers you found useful you can up-vote. The one you found most helpful, you can accept by clicking the check mark next to it.