# Why do we return *this in asignment operator and generally (and not &this) when we want to return a reference to the object?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, this, assignment-operator

I'm learning C++ and pointers and I thought I understood pointers until I saw this.

On one side the asterix(*) operator is dereferecing, which means it returns the value in the address the value is pointing to, and that the ampersand (&) operator is the opposite, and returns the address of where the value is stored in memory.

Reading now about assignment overloading, it says "we return `*this` because we want to return a reference to the object". Though from what I read `*this` actually returns the value of this, and actually `&this` logically should be returned if we want to return a reference to the object.

How does this add up? I guess I'm missing something here because I didn't find this question asked elsewhere, but the explanation seems like the complete opposite of what should be, regarding the logic of * to dereference, & get a reference.

For example here:

```
struct A {
  A& operator=(const A&) {
    cout << "A::operator=(const A&)" << endl;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Comment: `this` is a pointer to the current object. So using the *pointer-to* operator `&` (like `&this`) would give us a pointer to the pointer to the object (in your case with the type `A**`). You need to use the dereference operator `*` to get the object itself.

Comment: `*this` dereferences the this pointer giving you the current object. Remember that `this` is a pointer not an object. The `&` has more than 1 meaning depending on the context. It can be either a reference or to return the address of.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594378/address-of-operator-vs-reference-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594378/address-of-operator-vs-reference-operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is a pointer that keeps the address of the current object.  So dereferencing the pointer like `*this` you will get the lvalue of the current object itself. And the return type of the copy assignment operator of the presented class is  `A&`. So returning the expression `*this` you are returning a reference to the current object.

According to the C++ 17 Standard (8.1.2 This)

> 1 **The keyword this names a pointer to the object** for which a
> non-static member function (12.2.2.1) is invoked or a non-static data
> member’s initializer (12.2) is evaluated.

Consider the following code snippet as an simplified example.

```
int x = 10;

int *this_x = &x;
```

Now to return a reference to the object you need to use the expression `*this_x` as for example

```
std::cout << *this_x << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

`&` has multiple meanings depending on the context. In C and used alone, I can either be a bitwise AND operator or the address of something referenced by a symbol.

In C++, after a type name, it also means that what follows is a **reference** to an object of this type.

This means that is you enter :

```cpp
int     a = 0;
int &   b = a;
```

… `b` will become *de facto* an alias of `a`.

In your example, `operator=` is made to return an object of type A (not a pointer onto it). This will be seen this way by uppers functions, but what will actually be returned is an existing object, more specifically the instance of the class of which this member function has been called.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `*this` is (the value of?) the current object. But the pointer to the current object is `this`, not `&this`.

`&this`, **if** it was legal, would be a pointer-to-pointer to the current object. But it's illegal, since `this` (the pointer itself) is a temporary object, and you can't take addresses of those with `&`.

It would make more sense to ask why we don't do `return this;`.

The answer is: forming a pointer requires `&`, but forming a reference doesn't. Compare:

```
int x = 42;
```

```
int *ptr = &x;
int &ref =  x;
```

So, similarly:

```
int *f1() return {return &x;}
int &f1() return {return  x;}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple mnemonic you can use is that the `*` and `&` operators match the type syntax of the thing you're converting *from*, not the thing you're converting to:

- `*` converts a `foo*` to a `foo&`
- `&` converts a `foo&` to a `foo*`

In expressions, there's no meaningful difference between `foo` and `foo&`, so I could have said that `*` converts `foo*` to `foo`, but the version above is easier to remember.

C++ inherited its type syntax from C, and C type syntax named types after the expression syntax for using them, not the syntax for creating them. Arrays are written `foo x[...]` because you use them by accessing an element, and pointers are written `foo *x` because you use them by dereferencing them. Pointers to arrays are written `foo (*x)[...]` because you use them by dereferencing them and then accessing an element, while arrays of pointers are written `foo *x[...]` because you use them by accessing an element and then dereferencing it. People don't like the syntax, but it's consistent.

References were added later, and break the consistency, because there isn't any syntax for using a reference that differs from using the referenced object "directly". As a result, you shouldn't try to make sense of the type syntax for references. It just is.

The reason `this` is a pointer is also purely historical: `this` was added to C++ before references were. But since it is a pointer, and you need a reference, you have to use `*` to get rid of the `*`.

Comment: *"no meaningful difference between `foo` and `foo&`"* Mhm, [expressions can't have reference types](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Maybe you're agreeing with me, but if not: I think the paragraph you linked supports what I said. If `foo` and `foo&` were different, they would need to preserve the distinction in the further analysis. Since they aren't, they can simplify it by picking one notation, and they picked `foo`.

Comment: Yea, sorry if I wasn't clear, I'm agreeing with you.